# Can asp.net accomplish this?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, ajax, tomcat

I developed a simple webapp using tomcat/mysql. On the tomcat I use a REST interface to be able to interact with the client (using javascript). Since I have no knowledge of asp.net I would like to know whether asp.net could serve as a substitute for the above. I.e. provide a REST-Interface which I can contact using ajax and connect to a mysql database.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. However, [Windows Communication Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) would be a better technology to use for that.